# How to publicly share a Visual Studio Online Repository?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I was wondering if there was a way I could share my repository on VSO publicly? I use TFVC in Visual Studio, but I'll admit I'm new at it so I'm not really sure how to go about doing nor the steps to take to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE 2018-05-10 There is now limited public preview of Public projects in VSTS**

Join: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/04/27/vsts-public-projects-limited-preview/

I have joined and have made one of my projects public. There are still significant limitations in its capabilities and the current goal is to enable folks using GitHub for Issues and Code to now use VSTS for CI/CD.

Example: https://nkdagility.visualstudio.com/vsts-sync-migration

**While VSTS Public projects are still limited in capability you can still push your code to GitHub**

You can use the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.gittasks build tasks from the marketplace to publish/push your code to GitHub to make it public.

I do this with all of my Open Source projects so that i can use VSTS as primary and just post to GitHub. Even works to bring pull requests in from GitHub.

Example: https://github.com/nkdAgility/vsts-sync-migration

Comment: Is it still the case?

Comment: You can now sign up for an early preview of this feature.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/04/27/vsts-public-projects-limited-preview/