# VSO Share Repository Browse Only?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Not exactly like this - [How to publicly share a Visual Studio Online Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471403/how-to-publicly-share-a-visual-studio-online-repository/29496188#29496188) - I am trying to share the source code repository (Git) from Visual Studio Online to registered stakeholders. They need to get at the latest stuff at the Master branch to eval it along with work items. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have people with a Stakeholder license they won't be able to see the code. The Stakeholder license only gives access to:

- View team dashboards and portfolio backlogs
- View, add, and modify items on the backlog
- View, create, and modify work items such as stories, features, and bugs
- View, create, and save queries
- Create and receive alerts when changes are made to work items
- Submit, view, and change your feedback responses.

For people to see the code, they will at least need a Basic license. If you then want to restrict their access, you can do so by creating a TFS Group and setting the correct permissions. In this case, you want to limit the Code permissions to only Read so they can't modify the code.

See [Permission reference for Team Foundation Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx#git) for more information.

This means there is no free way to allow users to read your code. You do start with 5 free basic licenses however, so if that's enough you can assign those to your users.

Comment: Thanks Wouter. I will need some kind of other mechanism to share code then. Maybe some automation to bundle files into an archive when some kind of defined 'checkpoint' or label is made, and attach it to a work item. I will have to think on this.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to use Release Management to not only release the binaries but also the sources. Would that work for you? Or, if you're using Git, you can add a Github (private or public) repository and then manually push your changes to Github.