# Is it possible to make VSO (Visual Studio Online) repo be public visible?

Tags: azure-devops

I like VSO (Visual Studio Online) functionality and its abilities. But I want other users (anonymous) be able to view my repo of certain project.

I'was trying to work with the security stuff in project settings, but can't figure out how to set a public access to my repo.

Is it even possible?

Comment: This would be a great feature, we have some projects which we want to be open, so clients etc can pull and modify code repos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to publicly share a Visual Studio Online Repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471403/how-to-publicly-share-a-visual-studio-online-repository)

Comment: You can now sign up for an early preview of this feature.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/04/27/vsts-public-projects-limited-preview/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At present, no. VSTS is not currently intended to be a public code repository like GitHub.

## Update

As pointed out in the comments, public projects are an upcoming feature.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/04/27/vsts-public-projects-limited-preview/

Answer (score 1):

You can now change project visibility to public at Azure DevOps.
First you set  organization settings->Security-Policies -> Allow public projects
and then set project settings. It's well described at current Azure DevOps documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/make-project-public?view=azure-devops) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/public/create-public-project?tabs=new-nav&view=azure-devops#enable-anonymous-access-to-projects-for-your-organization)

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to sync the two, as outlined in [this](https://nkdagility.com/open-source-vsts-tfs-github-better-devops/) post.