# Sharing VSTS backlog board publicly

Tags: permissions, azure-devops

I am using VSTS work item tracking for personal projects and I want to share my progress with people who do not have access to my VSTS account.

Is it possible to achieve this ? Ideally, I would like to show a read-only backlog board for the project across iterations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make VSO (Visual Studio Online) repo be public visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519985/is-it-possible-to-make-vso-visual-studio-online-repo-be-public-visible)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I did come across that question, however it was specifically for code. I was wondering if work item tracking could have different behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If users are not have access to your VSTS account, they can’t view the backlog and board.

The  workaround is **add the users as stakeholder and only give them the permission to view the work items**. Detail settings as below:

1. Add users for stakeholder access level

   In https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_users page -> Add new users -> input the users email address and separate with semicolons for multiple users -> Access level as Stakeholder -> specify the project(s) you want them to view -> select Project Readers as VSTS Group -> Add.

   [image]
2. Set permissions for the project(s)

   In a project Security Tab https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_admin/_security -> select Reader group -> only set View Project-level information as Allow, others as Deny -> Save changes.

   [image]
3. Deny permission for stakeholders view build and release Tab

   In team project builds Tab, click Security -> set view build definition and view builds as deny -> Save changes.

   [image]

   In Release Tab, click … button for All release definitions -> security -> set view release definition and view releases as deny -> Save changes.

   [image]
   [image]

Now the stakeholders only can access to Work tab for the project. For other Tabs (Dashboards, Build and Release, Wiki), the users won't have permission to view and edit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps. I am assuming I can use a read-only PAT to pull the work item details and display them in a tool/website for public purpose.